# Is there a benefit to assigning a static IP to an instance instead of DHCP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, dhcp, amazon-vpc

We are creating a Windows AD instance in our AWS VPC and we're wondering if there is any benefit to assigning a static IP to that instance instead of using the default behavior of a subnet which is to assign a DHCP address. Given that the DHCP address will always be associated with that instance throughout the life of the instance until it's terminated I don't see an immediate benefit to using a static assignment. I also wonder how that would effect you if you ever wanted to clone the instance? Thoughts?

Comment: No impact on cloning -- static IPs in EC2/VPC are implemented as DHCP reservations.

Answer (score 1):

There are many benefits in private subnet:

- You have control over your IP allocation, can has some reasonable allocations (ie. .10-.49 for APP servers, .50-.59 for DBs)
- You can ensure that if you have VM with some task and need to recreate this VM, your IP will be unchanged
- You can have continous data in monitoring - when you recreate your instance with more resources, you can measure impact to load
- You can ensure that when you stop and start your instance, IP will be same (this is must have for me, I really don't want to active check if there is my instance and right instance on that IP/Hostname)
- You cansetup your on-instance firewall easilly

Unfortunatelly you cannot use static IP for autostalling groups (nor some subnet, like "this AG can associate only IP .100-.199").

Of course there is some drawbacks:

- You have to manage your IP allocation by yourself ie. check for conflicts
- It's not so "cloudy" as it could be. You cannot just add new instance, you need to find free IP for it
- In short - you have to have some basic knowledge about networking, you lost that "I can do whatever without tech knowledge" benefit, what is big reason why use clouds.

Unfortunatelly you cannot do it for public IP (you don't have your IP address block, public IPs are assigned dynamically across whole AWS), but you should have as less as possible public IPs at all (DB server really, really don't need to bu accessed from the Internet).